# How to "zoom"/"scale" in div's content with css or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The effect I am trying to achieve needs to keep the center in its place and zoom in the content while still maintaining the width and height of the div.

An example:

```
before -> after

 [x]      [X]
```

Or if you don't mind links [this site](http://www.hopi.cz/cs/) has it implemented on the homepage and its square containers

I have tried using the inspect element feature, but didn't really find any javascript calls or css on it. And google also didn't give me any tutorial, guess it's hard to name this effect.

Therefore, if someone could be so kind and forward me to a tutorial, function or give some tips I would greatly appreciate it.

Looking forward yo your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [CSS Transforms.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms)

On the website in question, this is implemented by way of

```
.view-tenth img {
    /* [other directives omitted] */
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.view-tenth:hover img {
    /* [other directives omitted] */
    transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0deg);
}
```

Comment: I do believe 'transition: >all<' is a bad practice. It's always better to be specific about transition options

Comment: @UtherTG - that is correct, albeit not in the scope of OP's question ;)

Comment: 1st of all thanks for this. What I still don't get is how to keep the original width and height of the image. When I apply the transition to my image when I hover over it it zooms in and increases its width and height as well. What am I missing?

Comment: Oh I am an idiot :D Completely forgot about the overflow property. thank you UtherTG, I am gonna look into the transforms to figure out what you guys were eon about with the "all" selector